# SSH to home network when machine behind router is connected to a VPN via tun0 iface

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, linux-networking, router

At home I have a network behind a **router**. Right now I am sitting in the office.

The router is connected to my **ISP** and I know my **IP**. (e.g. `11.22.33.44`)

I can **ping** the IP.

In the router I can enable **portforwarding** to specific IPs in the LAN.

I am forwarding **ssh** to one specific **PC**, so that I can connect to it with: `ssh -p 2345 mysshuser@11.22.33.44`. Everything works and is fine.

---

**But after connecting the PC with OpenVpn to my VPN Provider, I can't ssh into the machine anymore.**

The error is the following:

`ssh: connect to host 11.22.33.44 port 2345: Connection timed out`

---

I think I know that I must somehow **forward packets** from the `tun0` interface to **Local-Area-Network interface**, that OpenVpn creates to connect to the VPN provider, but I dont know how.

**Or is it not possible to have the PC connected to VPN and ssh into it?**

---

### Additional notes

- VPN-Provider is **NordVPN**
- I have read [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/517690/connect-to-a-machine-in-a-vpn-via-ssh-with-dynamic-dns?rq=1), but the issue seems VPN **provider specific**, so i don't think its a duplicate
- I have found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365285/how-to-allow-ssh-into-terminal-after-connecting-to-vpn-server-using-nordvpn-serv) and I am asking myself, wether or not this breaks the privacy aspect of the VPN?
- Also [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893775/cant-ssh-to-server-with-vpn-connection) seems to be solving the issue, but again the question wether or not this **breaks the privacy of my VPN** is my question?

---

### EDIT

I could solve my problem using the links provided in **Additional Notes**.

**But could someone clarify the security aspect of this routing? Is my privacy compromised now?**

Comment: No, it does not compromise the privacy aspect. The main goal of source base routing is providing a way to answer for an incoming connection when multiple uplinks exist. Or basically it tells the PC to answer via given interface if the connection was initiated through it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have multiple default gateways in your route table. You need to set up policy routing at your PC. It is called [source based policy routing](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html).

PS. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)